# Is there a way to force Monodevelop to add/remove 'ProductVersion' and 'SchemaVersion' to/from .csproj file?

Tags: git, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I'm currently using MonoDevelop (4.0.12) on Linux and Xamarin Studio (5.1.2) on Windows. The Linux version always adds the following Tags to the `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <ProductVersion>12.0.0</ProductVersion>
  <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

where as the Windows version always completely removes them. Is there a way to make both versions behave consistently? Either both adding these tags or both removing them?

It gets really annoying, because I develop on both machines and I want to version the project file in git. So completely ignoring said file is no option. Filters are no option as well, because they don't get committed to remote.

Comment: Best/easiest way would probably be to checkout and build version 5.1.2 on Linux...

Comment: Well, unfortunately I am not able to compile it under Linux. It throws some errors about invalid arguments in overloaded methods. I'd also prefer a solution where I could keep using MonoDevelop 4.0.